# ngOnInit - Waiting for Observable Subscribe To Manipulate outcome Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

I am trying to get min / max validator in my template.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.app.object$.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive)).subscribe(object=> {
      this.object= object;});

     this.objectMin= object.min.find(x => x.name === "min11").value;

}
```

I am trying to use objectMin (number) in my template..however as observable has not finish subscription yet, object remains undefined and thus, objectMin also remains undefined..

any solutions ?

thanks!

Comment: There are couple of ways to solve it and it depends on how your template uses `objectMin`. We will be able to help if you could share the template code.

Comment: Hi, on the template, I will be using objectMin as a number to pass inside my <currency-input> component selector which accepts [min] as number value

Comment: <currency-input
    [form]="formGroup"
    [min]="objectMin"> --> this min accepts a number

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of solution for this. The best approach would be to have an observable which will wrap your `objectMin` like this:

1. Have a class level observable variable like this:

   `objectMin$: Observable<number>;`
2. Initialize this observable in `ngOnInit()` like this -

   ngOnInit() {

   ```
   this.objectMin$ = this.app.object$.pipe(
                            takeWhile(() => this.alive),                                 
                            map((object) => {
                              this.object = object;
                              return object.min.find(x => x.name === "min11").value;
                            })
                     );}
   ```
3. Use `async` pipe in the template to unwrap the value like this: `<currency-input [form]="formGroup"[min]="objectMin$ | async">`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to implement...it shows me error at "map"... Cannot find name 'map'.

Comment: `map` is a rxjs operator. import it like you imported `takeWhile`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesn't work...I am putting debuggers to see what's happening..it hits the observable but doesn't go inside it

Comment: make sure `takeWhile` condition becomes true. Try without `takeWhile` as well.

Comment: takeWhile remains true from the first time it hits debugger...I tried without takeWhile also..it doesn't work...usually in subscribe 1st time when it hits debuggers it is null and 2nd time the object gets populated...however in this method, I don't see my debugger being hit 2nd time